# Advices on creating a first e-Commerce application?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I need to create a e-commerce application in PHP.
As a first option I though to use Magento, that I already used one or two times in the past.
But as the requirements are growing, I think Magento is not correct choice, there are too much options I don't need, and some options which are not available and/or some customization which will be difficult.

So I think I'll write it from the scratch using Zend Framework which I'm used too.

Do you have any advices to start ?

I think for example about :

- Session storing (filesystem <-> db) ?
- Payment module security (Paypal, CB, and checks)
- Computation with SQL Stored Procedures ?

What is yours ?

Comment: Might be better off as community wiki

Answer (score 1):

[Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) could interest you, it is used to check against valid credit card number

Not really an anwser but I would suggest you to think about payment informations storage (credit card number, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/). It is light-weight, fast, reliable with all the almost all the features needed for an ecommerce solution.

> OpenCart is a turn-key ready "out of
>   the box" shopping cart solution. You
>   simply install, select your template,
>   add products and your ready to start
>   accepting orders.

[Have  a look at the features as well.](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=feature/feature)